# Using variables instead of column names or numbers

Tags: vba, variables, excel

I'm trying to draw a chart in Excel and here is my code

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'ResultHL'!$E:$E")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='ResultHL'!$CB$1:$CB$2520"
```

This is working fine but I'd like t know whether i can assign column names or numbers to some variables and use it in the above code.

In line 2--> `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'ResultHL'!$E:$E")`
i need to assign E to a variable and use it

also in line 5, i need to use an integer variable instead of 2520

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I find it's much easier to use the `Cells` and/or `Resize` properties than to get bogged down in all this messy string concatenation business.

Example:

```
Dim rngApples As Range
Dim shtResults As Worksheet
Dim lngMaxRow As Long

shtResults = Worksheets("Sheet1")

' Define the range you want to plot
lngMaxRow = 2520
rngApples = shtResults.Range("CB1").Resize(lngMaxRow, 1)

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = rngApples
```

Alternatively, you can define your range as follows:

```
lngColNum = 56 ' or whatever CB is
lngMaxRow = 2520
rngApples = shtResults.Range(Cells(1, lngColNum), Cells(lngMaxRow, lngColNum))
```

Comment: Absolutely.  Using strings to manipulate cell ranges in VBA is cumbersome at best, completely unmaintainable at worst.

Answer (score 1):

The cell & range specifiers are just strings, so you can concantenate them with strings or numbers to reference the cells you want.

```
For example:
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'ResultHL'!$E:$E")
Could become
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'ResultHL'!$" & ColumnName & ":$" & ColumnName)
Where ColumnName is the string value of the column you wish to use.
```

And

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='ResultHL'!$CB$1:$CB$2520"
Could become
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='ResultHL'!$CB$1:$CB$" & MaxRowNumber
```